# Moving layer to front does not make it visible

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I am a newbie trying to design a simple camera icon in Photoshop CC on Mac. I want have two circles, called "Lens" and "Lens rim", as well as the layer "Frame", which is the light grey camera frame. The lens is grey and the lens rim is black. The lens rim is slightly larger than the lens, and I want the black rim to surround the grey lens, so I place the lens layer to be in front, and the lens rim to be behind, but in front of the frame. However, all I see is the black lens rim and the frame. Re-arranging the layers doesn't change anything. Both the lens and the lens rim layers have opacity set to 100%.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the layer thumbnail that although your layer is at 100% opacity, it is in fact not 100% opaque.

All drawing tools in Photoshop have an opacity setting, which will draw at that opacity, leaving you with permanently transparent layers. I assume that is what you've done.

[image]

Since you're working with shapes you should really — rather than drawing pixels — be working with vector shape layers, which you can easily scale, transform, change appearance etc.

[image]

See [**Adobe Support — Working with vector-based shape layers**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/atv/cs6-tutorials/working-with-vector-based-shape-layers.html)